# Visual Basic Text File Manipulation

Tags: vb.net

Updated code.

```
Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
    Dim xString = File.ReadAllLines("C:\test\bbooktest.csv")
    Dim qString As String = Nothing
    For Each myItem In lstboxSerialout.Items

        For Each x As String In xString
            If x.Contains(myItem) And x.Contains(",  ***,") Then
                qString = qString & x.Replace(",  ***,", ",  " & txtboxdateshpd.Text & ",") & vbCrLf
            Else
                qString = qString & x & vbCrLf
            End If
        Next
    Next
    File.WriteAllText("C:\test\bbooktest.csv", qString)
End Sub
```

This is the result I am getting when I run this.

```
MANUFACTURER,MODEL,SERIAL ,TYPE,Size,DATE REC,MFG NAME ,DATE SHIP,COMMENTS
Test Company,  Test Model,123456,Test Type,Test Size,20150917,*****,2015,******  
Test Company,  Test Model,434343,Test Type,Test Size,20150917,*****,***,*******  
Test Company,  Test Model,789456,Test Type,Test Size,20150917,*****,***,*******
MANUFACTURER,MODEL,SERIAL ,TYPE,Size,DATE REC,MFG NAME ,DATE SHIP,COMMENTS
Test Company,  Test Model,  123456,  Test Type,  Test Size,  20150917,  ******,  ***,  ********
Test Company,  Test Model,  434343,  Test Type,  Test Size,  20150917,  ******,  2015,  ********
Test Company,  Test Model,  789456,  Test Type,  Test Size,  20150917,  ******,  ***,  ********
MANUFACTURER,MODEL,SERIAL ,TYPE,Size,DATE REC,MFG NAME ,DATE SHIP,COMMENTS
Test Company,  Test Model,  123456,  Test Type,  Test Size,  20150917,  ******,  ***,  ********
Test Company,  Test Model,  434343,  Test Type,  Test Size,  20150917,  ******,  ***,  ********
Test Company,  Test Model,  789456,  Test Type,  Test Size,  20150917,  ******,  2015,  ********
```

When I want it to look this this

```
MANUFACTURER,MODEL,SERIAL ,TYPE,Size,DATE REC,MFG NAME ,DATE SHIP,COMMENTS
Test Company,  Test Model,123456,  Test Type,  Test Size,20150917,  ******,2015,  ********
Test Company,  Test Model,434343,  Test Type,  Test Size,20150917,  ******,2015,  ********
Test Company,  Test Model,789456,  Test Type,  Test Size,20150917,  ******,2015,  ********
```

Im sorry for the incredibly poor formatting I am working on making it look less crazy.

Comment: Since the data is a CSV, you could read it in very easily to a DataTable or List(of T) and refer to them as columns or properties without parsing text

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: This assume that the serial number is unique over all data set. What if a model name contain the exact digit of an others serial number? Your replace should put the coma back: ",test," instead of "test"

Comment: Thank you everyone for replying so quickly. Plutonix thank you for that advice I have never worked with that before and I will most certainly look in to that.  Thomas Krojer I am struggling to have it find and exact match ( I had purposely put similar serial numbers in and listed the lines in a text box and it finds all the ones with similarities in them and listed the lines for me) so my logic I assume is missing something ( as usual ) the lotus I will try what you mentioned and I will write back soon.  Thank you all again for writing so quickly and not ripping me for my noob questions.

Comment: For some reason when I went to try what you had suggested the_lotus it did not modify the file at all. I went and looked and I realized the only way I had got it to write anything to the line was  `.Replace("***", "test")` the difference is I removed the commas from the ***. I tried what you had suggested with the commas before and after the test but it is not writing to the file at all. When I run it the way I had mentioned it gives me this for output.   _Test Company,  Test Model,  T123456,  Test Type,  Test Size,  20150909,  testtest,  test,  testtest*_

Comment: Does any other program use the data file? Is CSV required? If your program is the only one to create, update, and delete data consider using a `DataTable`, or collection/class, with persistence (search for it.) If other programs use the file at the same time a database is a better solution.

Comment: This will be the only program that will use this csv file. I was orignally looking into using xlsx files but I have less knowledge of excel than I do of a raw data file.  I have successfully written code that "Logs in" the pieces into an excel spreadsheet but my lack of knowledge of excel has made it even more difficult for me to search through the spreadsheet and edit it based on exact word matching from certain columns.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. I have it working "somewhat" the way I would like it to but know I have another problem. I have changed the code up top to show what I now have.

Answer (score 0):

Move `Dim xString = File.ReadAllLines("C:\test\bbooktest.csv")` outside the `For Each myItem` loop.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I tried that and I am still getting the same result.